# ListView won't scroll vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scrollviewer

I have a number of elements inside a `TabItem` and I want to make the `ListView` scrollable vertically but have the buttons remain at the top (not scroll). I tried wrapping the `ListView` in a `ScrollViewer` but it will not scroll. I can put the `ScrollViewer` outside the `ItemsControl` and update the `RowDefinition Height="*"` and all the contents scroll including the buttons, but that is not what I need.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>       

    <Menu Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Options" />
        <MenuItem Header="Help" />
    </Menu>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Test" Height="23" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="2" >
        <TabItem Header="TabItem1">
            <ItemsControl>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Command="{Binding Button1}" Width="150" Margin="5" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Button1</Button>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Button2}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView}" Width="150" Margin="5" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Button2</Button>
                </StackPanel>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <ListView Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Width="Auto" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ItemsControl>
        </TabItem>

        ... Other tabs
    </TabControl>   
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `ItemsControl`, which be default will put items in vertical `StackPanel` which gives its children unlimited amount of height to grow. In other words `ListView` has unlimited height to grow to accommodate all items hence won't show scrollbar. Use `Grid` instead and then you don't need `ScrollViewer`. It's part of default template for `ListView` anyway

```xml
<TabItem Header="TabItem1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Command="{Binding Button1}" Width="150" Margin="5" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Button1</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding Button2}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView}" Width="150" Margin="5" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Button2</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Width="Auto" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

also in the main `Grid` don't set last row (one that contains `TabControl`) height to auto as this will give `TabControl` amount of space to fit whole `ListView` without scrolling

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```